# Тестирование. Заменить URL реальной базы на тестовую

Tags: python, тестирование, sqlalchemy

Есть файл `database` с таким содержимым

```
engine = create_async_engine(settings.DATABASE_URL, echo=False, future=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


async def init_database():
    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

Как мне подменить при тестировании `settings.DATABASE_URL` на тестовую базу данных в `conftest.py` чтобы при каждом вызове `get_session()` в разных местах получать подключение к тестовой, а не реальной базе данных?

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю следующее решение: создаем фикстуру на тесты и в ней переписываем подключение к БД.

Пример:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def temp_db() -> Generator:
    engine = create_engine(TEST_DB_URL)
    # Добавляете свои параметры на sessionmaker()
    testing_session = sessionmaker()
    # Здесь создаете метадату в зависимости от используемого подхода
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    def override_get_session():
        try:
            db = testing_session()
            yield db
        finally:
            db.close()  # noqa

    # тут перезаписывайте зависимости своего приложения на метод get_session

    try:
        base = testing_session()
        yield base
    finally:
        base.close()  # noqa
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте возможность задания конфигурации приложения с помощью переменных окружения. Это в любом случае полезно, обычно в разных средах разные параметры.

То есть, если сейчас у вас параметр зашит в код:

```
DATABASE_URL="some-url"
```

замените это на:

```
import os

DATABASE_URL=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', "some-url")
```

Теперь при запуске можно указывать БД в переменной окружения.

В pytest для этого можно использовать плагины [pytest-dotenv](https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv) или [pytest-env](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env).

Для pytest-dotenv в pytest.ini добавьте конфигурацию:

```
[pytest]
env_files =
    .test.env
```

А в файле `.test.env` задайте переменные окружения:

```
DATABASE_URL=some-test-db-url
```